# How do I remove all types of translation from wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

Few days ago I installed my website with Bitnami with Azure Cloud server. I installed WordPress as my site, but Bitnami WordPress comes with all kind of language translation. I always use English and don't like to see any translation.

Problem is when ever I update any plugin or theme it also comes with all of those translation. I didn't start posting on my site. Also I searched everywhere for this solution but there are no solution what I'm looking for.

Is there any way to only use English as my site language and remove all those translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename or delete the following directory:

/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/languages

For my setup (on AWS) that did the trick.

I did this based on the clues found here: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/#change-language-manually

HTH